# Method is illegal start of expression

Tags: java, methods

Below is some code that tries to find the first word above a certain amount of characters.

```
public class FirstMatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("aliceInWonderland.txt"));
        String longWord = "";
        boolean found = false;

        public void threshold (int Threshold) {
            while (in.hasNext() && !found) {
                String word = in.next();
                if (word.length() > Threshold) {
                    longWord = word;
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The first long word is: " + longWord);
        }
    }
}
```

(In the above code I didn't copy in all the import statements)
For some reason for my threshold method it returns illegal start of expression. I think it is a stupid mistake but can't figure out what's wrong...

Comment: Why would you even think that you can implement a method inside another one (unless it isn't part of any anonymous or internal class)?

Comment: Could be new to Java, having worked in a language which supports [nested functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function).

Answer (score 3):

You should declare your `threshold` method out of the `main` method.

A method can only be created at class level, and not inside another method.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstMatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("aliceInWonderland.txt"));    
        threshold(in, 10);
    }

    public static void threshold(Scanner in, int threshold) {
        String longWord = "";
        boolean found = false;
        while (in.hasNext() && !found) {
            String word = in.next();
            if (word.length() > threshold) {
                longWord = word;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The first long word is: " + longWord);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do I have to do that? What is causing the error?

Comment: @Sruli public static void main(String[] args) is a method. You cannot create a method inside another method-- which is what you're trying to do with 'public void threshold (int Threshold)'

Comment: @Sruli In Java methods can be declared only at class-level, not in different method.

Comment: inside a method declaration you are not allowed to have an inner method declaration. A method declaration is a class member (like a field) and should reside immediately under the classes braces `{ member declarations }`.